# how to get structure from QByteArray

Tags: c#, c++, c, qt, qtnetwork

i have a TCP Communication application in C# and other in C++ Qt Program on linux

But after communication i get data from C# application in C++ QByteArray.
 now QByteArray needs to be converted back to struct

How can i get data in my_struct in QT.
i have used

```
QDataStream in(&data, QIODevice::ReadOnly);
int parID;
QString parMessage;
in >> parID >>parMessage;
```

OR

```
const my_struct* my_struct = reinterpret_cast<const my_struct* >(data.constData());
// display
qDebug() << " id :"<<my_struct->id<< " msg: "<< my_struct->msg;



struct my_struct
{
  int id;
  string msg;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

QDataStream uses own serialization/deserialization format. It looks like your data isnt serialized using QDataStream. To solve the issue you can send data in json/xml/etc.

Comment: That's not quite correct. `QDataStream` certainly uses its own simple format for complex Qt data types. For simple types, such as numerical types, there's really nothing much to it: you select the endianness and are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how it was sent. You need to be sure of the formatting on both side before you can properly communicate.

Sending a String is tricky your best bet would be to send the length of the string (as a 32-bit unsinged int) and then the data (in the utf8 format) and when you read you can do

```
char* s;
int length;
in.readData(s, length);
QString str = QString::fromUtf8(s, length);
delete[] s;//free the allocated buffer
```